# how to handle page event in a user control?

Tags: asp.net, events

If a certain control is included on a page, I have some code that I need executed at PreRenderComplete time. FYI: The control happens to contain a menu, and the code I want executed mangles URLs in hyperlinks to include information needed by the menu, but I don't think the specifics matter to my question. I have to do this after the DataBound event of all controls because Repeaters and GridViews and whatever might include hyperlinks.

But I can't figure out how to attach a handler to a page event from within a control. Is there a way to do this?

I could add the handler to every page, of course, but that would mean repeating the same code on every page, and any time someone created a new page they'd have to know and remember to add this call.

I tried attaching to events in the user control but there doesn't seem to be one that executes at the right time in the page life cycle.

If this is the wrong way to go about this and you have an idea for a different approach, I'm happy to hear it.

Comment: "I tried attaching to events in the user control but there doesn't seem to be one that executes at the right time in the page life cycle." Where did you try?

Comment: I tried using the PreRender event, but that happens before data binding so it doesn't work. I looked at lists of events and I didn't see one that happens after data binding but before setting the view state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code should work for you:

```
public partial class PageEventsUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.PreRenderComplete += Page_PreRenderComplete;
    }

    private void Page_PreRenderComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! You're a genius! I should have mentioned that I'm writing in Visual Basic so I actually had to say "AddHandler Me.Page.PreRenderComplete, AddressOf Page_PreRenderComplete", but that worked.